# Combining multiple results into result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get an obsolete number value for two of my columns but because my case statement contains terminalid column I am required to group by terminal id which gives me multiple values.

Query:

```sql
SELECT
    storenumber,
    bbbtendertypetext,
    
    CASE WHEN terminalnumber > 91 THEN
        SUM( financialamounttendered ) - SUM( financialchangeamount )
    END AS sco_net_value,

    CASE WHEN terminalnumber < 91 THEN
        SUM( financialamounttendered ) - SUM( financialchangeamount )
    END AS front_end_net_value,

    COUNT( transactionid ) AS transaction_count

FROM
    AceTLogData.Tlog.tender

WHERE
    transactiondatetime > '2022-09-21 00:00:00.000'
    AND
    transactiondatetime < '2022-09-22 00:03:00.000'

GROUP BY
    storenumber,
    terminalnumber,
    bbbtendertypetext

ORDER BY
    storenumber;
```

**Sample output **:

[image]

In the image you can see visa and gift card is coming in twice since they belong to two different terminals. So I am trying to see on how can I combine those duplicates in one so my SCO net sales, and transaction count would update as well.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What is the significance of the `terminalnumber` column? What does it _mean_?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` expression inside aggregate function call, then you don't need to include the column in `GROUP BY` section. Something like that:

```
WITH d AS (
    SELECT 6 AS storeNumber, 'GiftCard' AS tenderType, 21 as terminalNumber, 243 AS transactionId, 42 AS amount
    UNION ALL SELECT 6 AS storeNumber, 'GiftCard' AS tenderType, 100 as terminalNumber, 243 AS transactionId, 27 AS amount
)
SELECT
    storeNumber,
    tenderType,
    SUM(CASE WHEN terminalNumber < 91 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS sumTerminalType1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN terminalNumber > 91 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS sumTerminalType2
FROM d
GROUP BY storeNumber, tenderType
```

Comment: Thank you i used  case inside aggregate function  and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

SELECT storenumber,
bbbtendertypetext,
Sum(case when TerminalNumber>91 then (financialamounttendered -
financialchangeamount)end) AS SCO_NET_VALUE,
Sum(case when TerminalNumber<91 then (financialamounttendered -
financialchangeamount)end) AS FRONT_END_NET_VALUE,
Count(transactionid)                                      AS
Transaction_Count
FROM   [AceTLogData].[Tlog].[tender]
WHERE  transactiondatetime > '2022-09-21 00:00:00.000'
AND transactiondatetime < '2022-09-22 00:03:00.000'
GROUP  BY storenumber,
bbbtendertypetext``
ORDER  BY storenumber;

Comment: PLease format your code to make it readable (use ```` blocks)